# Prove that factoradic method gives $k$-th lexicographical permutation.

Tags: permutations, algorithms

Factoradic method can be used to get $k$-th lexicographic permutation of $n$-elements.

The factoradic method is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations.

### Could you please kindly provide the proof that this method gives the $k$-th permutation.

I have described the method from Wikipedia below.

---

There are two steps to get the $k$-th permutation:

**Step-1. Convert $k$ to factorial number system.**

Eg: to get $2982$nd permutation of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ convert $2892$ to factorial number system. This gives

$2892 = 4:0:4:1:0:0:0_!$ $(\because 2892 = 4 \times 6! + 0\times 5! + 4 \times 4! + 1 \times 3! + 0 \times 2! + 0 \times 1! + 0 \times 0!)$

**Step-2: Get $k$-th permutation from the above representation in factorial number system using the method described below.**

We start with the following initial state and transfer elements from source to the permutation array in a order directed by the digits of $k$ represented in factorial number system.

*Initial state*

- Permutation  array: $\{\}$ // Initially it is empty.
- Source : $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. // Lexicographically lowest permutation.
- $k$, here $2892$ = $4:0:4:1:0:0:0_!$.

*Zeroth transfer*

First (most significant) digit of $k$ in factorial number system is $4$. So transfer $4$-th element from the source to the permutation array. Now we state is as follows:

- Permutation  array: $\{4\}$ // Initially it is empty.
- Source : $\{0,1,2,3,5,6\}$. // Lexicographically lowest permutation.
- $k$, here $2892$ = $4:0:4:1:0:0:0_!$.

*First transfer*

Next digit of $k$ is $0$, so transfer zeroth element of source. The state becomes

- Permutation  array: $\{4,0\}$ // Initially it is empty.
- Source : $\{1,2,3,5,6\}$. // Lexicographically lowest permutation.
- $k$, here $2892$ = $4:0:4:1:0:0:0_!$.

*Second transfer*

Next digit of $k$ is $4$. Transfer $4$-th element of the source.

- Permutation  array: $\{4,0,6\}$ // Initially it is empty.
- Source : $\{1,2,3,5\}$. // Lexicographically lowest permutation.
- $k$, here $2892$ = $4:0:4:1:0:0:0_!$.

$\cdots$ and so on give the permutation ${4,0,6,2,1,3,5}$.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations

---

## Update

After going through the comments and this Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code), I understand that the second step in the above procedure is just decoding Lehemer code to its corresponding permutation. So, the most significant part for me is **step-1**. Therefore my question condenses to the following question:

### Prove that the digits of $k$ in factoradiac system gives the Lehmer code for the $k$-th permutation.

Comment: Look at the very thorough presentation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1400468/305862).

Comment: Depending on what intermediate results that are acceptable to you, an alternate demonstration would be by induction.  If you are choosing $k$ digits from $\{0,1,2,\cdots, (n-1)\}$, where $k < n$, you can let $f(k)$ denote the enumeration of possible constructible numbers.  Clearly, $f(1) = n$.  Assume that $\displaystyle f(k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}.$  For any such $k$ digit number, $k$ of the $n$ digits has been used.  So, there will be $(n-k)$ choices for the next digit, when constructing a satisfying # with $(k+1)$ digits.  So, $~\displaystyle f(k+1) = f(k) \times (n-k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!}.$

Comment: @Jean Marie Thank you very much! I think I am one step closer to the answer to my question. I understand how a permutation can be encoded by  Lehmer code. And,  I think when $k$ is written in factoradic system, it gives the Lehmer code for $k$-th permutation. However, I still do not understand how to prove this last part. I appreciate any help!